# jQuery scrollTo code assistance

Tags: jquery, scrollto, scrolltop

Can somebody please explain why this won't work?
Ideally, when the link at the top is clicked, it should scroll down to my other class.
I also don't understand a lot of this code, so a detailed explanation would be great!

```
$('a.scrollto').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top-25
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that each anchor with class "scrollto" has a HREF which points to an Class (or ID is more suggested). For example:

```
<a href="#goToThisAnchor" class="scrollto">Scroll to #goToThisAnchor</a>
```

Clicking the above anchor will scroll down to the element that has `id="goToThisAnchor`

```
//Put's the click event listeners on anchor elements with class name 'scrollto'
$('a.scrollto').click(function(){  
    $('html, body').animate({ //animates the html and body (this makes the scroll effect)
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top-25 //choose which element to scroll to in this case it will choose the element that is specified in the "href" of the anchor clicked. offset().top gives the position offset from the TOP of .your_class_name
    }, 500); //500 is the time in milliseconds it will take to scroll.
    return false; //cancels your anchor from following it's href
});
```

I would actually suggest using an ID instead of a class name to scroll to, or else the scrollTop will just scroll to the first element with the "class name" it sees.

You want to have this anchor to click on to scroll down to #rulesa:

```
<a href="#rulesa" class="scrollto">Scroll to #rulesa</a>
```

Clicking this anchor will scroll you to the element that has **id="rulesa"**. Notice that the id is contained in the href.

**My Apologies**, using the following code will work:

```
$('a.scrollto').click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({ 
     scrollTop: $("#rulespng").offset().top-25
  }, 500);
return false;
```

**BUT** You will have to recreate this function for EACH ID anchor you want to scroll to. Which is FINE, if you want all `a.scrollto` to scroll to just 1 anchor point: `#rulespng`

**BUT** If you use the original code it will be much more **flexible**:

```
scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top-25
```

You only need the one function listed at the top (which you also wrote in your original question), and it will work for ALL anchors with `$('a.scrollto')`, just depending on the href attribute of the anchor explained above.

Comment: ok Thanks for the help. The id of the object I intend on scrolling to is #rulesa and it has a class of .scrollsto, so should I put #rulesa where you have 'your_class_name'?

Comment: @TomSimpson I updated my answer again :p see the Markup you need to have to make it work.

Comment: @TomSimpson, yes you could do that. But my original answer wasn't as scalable. I'll update the answer to show the markup you should use with the information you provided.

Comment: IT JUST WORKED!
THANKS, YOUR HELP WAS APPRECIATED!

Comment: this is the code I used
'code'
 $('a.scrollto').click(function(){  
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $("#rulespng").offset().top-25 
  }, 500);
  return false;
'/code'

Comment: @TomSimpson Glad to hear it worked! Please try looking at my updated code and trying to get that to work. I will explain why in my answer. Apologies for the confusion. Also, it would be appreciated if you mark my answer as accepted, if it works for you. Thanks :)

Comment: thanks, I will go back to the original then, but one problem I have just noticed is that it continues to scroll to the bottom after it reaches where I want it to?

Comment: @TomSimpson Did you try the original code in the format that I suggested in my answer? It should work. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/WtnTM/ If it isn't working yet, please edit your question and include your scrollTo jquery and also your HTML anchor links.